# How do I put notification alert on the border of the table?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, redux

Does anybody know how to place this icon("15" it's notification alert) on the border of the table using react. It stays between and elements. I tried to google some solutions,but couldn't find it.

DESIGN PIC: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKZzE.png)

Comment: This seems to be a css related issue not react specific. If you are using css in js solution to implement your styles then please add the code you tried so far.

Comment: I don't know where to place it in react, so i haven't even started with css :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

```html
<section class="block">
  <div class="badge"></div>
</section>
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  /* move it based on the parent position */
}
```

### Another version in JSX

```
export default function BlockWithBadge({ badge, children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="block">
        <div className="badge">{ badge }</div>
        { children }
      </section>
      <style jsx scoped>{`
        .block {
          position: relative;
        }

        .badge {
          position: absolute;
          /* move it based on the parent position */
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

### Another version in TSX

```
import type { ReactNode } from "react";

export interface BlockWithBadgeProps {
  badge: number;
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function BlockWithBadge({ badge, children }: BlockWithBadgeProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="block">
        <div className="badge">{ badge }</div>
        { children }
      </section>
      <style jsx scoped>{`
        .block {
          position: relative;
        }

        .badge {
          position: absolute;
          /* move it based on the parent position */
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

### How?

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

### Full Example

[image: The screenshot of my work on JSFiddle]

https://jsfiddle.net/pan93412/L809udzq/

I've written the full comment there.